# Problem redirect in php (Wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning,

I am currently alternating and I have to develop a wordpress plugin for my company for 2 sites.

I have a problem with redirection in my code because on one site it works but on the other it comes back on the same page with a little HTML.

My Code:

```php
            // Pour faire une redirection //
            $url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/confirmation-success-rdv";
            
            
            
            if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {
                $location = apply_filters('wp_redirect', $url, 302);
                
                header( "Location: $location", true, 302);
                Exit();
            }
```

Before redirect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61OGj.jpg)

after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D29mQ.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand, why you are making the redirect a condition, and follow it up with another redirect? 
you could just `wp_redirect( $url, 302 ); exit;`

Comment: or `if ( wp_redirect( $url, 302 ) ) {
    exit;
}`

Comment: Good morning,
I had tried like your example that didn’t work so I added a condition to check if redirection is possible. But it still didn’t work.